# Powershell or other script to swap mouse buttons?

Tags: windows-7, mac, mouse, boot-camp

I'm wondering if this is possible. I use a Macbook, running Windows 7...when I don't have an external mouse connected, I leave the left/right settings of the buttons to the default. But when I plug in a mouse, I change that setting (since I use the mouse left-handed).

What I'd like is a simple Powershell script, or Windows script or something along those lines that I could keep on the desktop and run at the appropriate time. I don't necessarily care about having it automatic (when I plug in or remove the mouse).

Answer (score 6):

I tried this PowerShell on a Windows PC; I don't have a Windows setup on my BootCamp to test your exact scenario.

It swapped my buttons for the mouse only. It left the touchpad and pointing stick right-handed.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

$SwapButtons = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SwapMouseButton(bool swap);
'@ -Name "NativeMethods" -Namespace "PInvoke" -PassThru

Write-Host "Mouse buttons currently swapped?" ([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::MouseButtonsSwapped)

[bool]$returnValue = $SwapButtons::SwapMouseButton(!([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::MouseButtonsSwapped))

Write-Host "Mouse buttons currently swapped?" ([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::MouseButtonsSwapped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some mice (Logitech) can be set to be used left handed without changing windows settings. Other then that, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

[**Mouse Mixer**](http://www.fxc.btinternet.co.uk/software.htm) makes it easier to change the primary button of the mouse:

> This application enables quick and
>   easy swapping of the primary mouse
>   button. One click will automatically
>   change from left to right and vice
>   versa.

You could combine this with a program that allows to run other programs when USB events are detected, like [**USB Safely Remove**](http://safelyremove.com/) for instance.

> Another USB Safely Remove feature that
>   distinguishes it from similar software
>   is starting any applications not only
>   after connecting a device, but also
>   before removing it. The autorun
>   feature allows you to set up data
>   backup before disconnecting a
>   removable hard drive, to run Total
>   Commander with the contents of the
>   pen-drive, automatically unmount an
>   encrypted TrueCrypt drive before
>   disconnecting the USB media, etc.

[image]

Comment: Interesting looking programs, but a little more complex than I'm wanting...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Macbook running Bootcamp to test this right now, but as I recall, there's a setting for where on the *touchpad* the right-click zone should be, which is separate from the setting for the mouse right/left buttons in the Windows control panel. Click on the Boot Camp icon in the notification bar, and select "Boot Camp Control Panel". There should be a tab for touchpad settings; use this to select a different touchpad right-click zone. The right/left settings for the external mouse should remain the same.

**Update:**
Here is a screenshot of what the boot camp control panel options should look like. Right where it says "Secondary Click" on the lower left, you can use the dropdown menu to change it from "bottom right corner" to "bottom left corner" or vice-versa. If this option does not appear, you may need to update your bootcamp drivers, which you can do by downloading the most recent bootcamp updates [from Apple](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/).

[image: boot camp right click region]

You should be able to set your mouse settings in the Windows control panel to be for a left-handed mouse, then set your touchpad settings using this method to be right-handed.

Comment: This might work, I'll have to check my boot camp settings when I'm at that laptop next.

Comment: My bootcamp settings don't look like that. I don't have that Secondary Click under 1 finger. :/

Comment: Have you tried updating your bootcamp drivers to the latest version?